# Get information about friends of friends using the graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get some information about friends of friends of my user.
Specifically, I would like to get their name, age, picture, friends list, groups, interests, likes etc.

I'm fairly new to the whole FB API, and I'd be very thankful for any help.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

It is basically a sandbox for building up api calls to get information about your users.

Here is an example of the request you can send off to Facebook and the response you can get back:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<FBID>?fields=id,name,friends.fields(last_name)&method=GET&format=json&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

And the response:

```
{
 "id": "<MY FBID>", 
 "name": "<MY NAME>", 
 "friends": {
   "data": [
     {
       "last_name": "<FRIEND LAST NAME>", 
       "id": "<FRIEND FBID>"
     }, 
     {
       "last_name": "<FRIEND LAST NAME>", 
       "id": "<FRIEND FBID>"
     }, 
     etc...
```